# Searching for single buildings in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute

I want to search for different buildings by using the labels I've added to them.

[image: example]

Like for instance, I want to search for the building with the label `"1630"`, as in the picture. Is there any specific function or a plug-in for searching?

Comment: if one of the answers below answers your question don't forget to mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use the `'Select by Expression'` tool to find the buildings with the matching labels.

1. When the field contains strings:
   `"YourFieldNameWithLabels" ILIKE '1630'`
2. In the case the field is an integer:
   `"YourFieldNameWithLabels" = 1630`

You'll get the labels selected and You can then use the `'Map Map to Selection'` button.

Answer (score 4):

@geom's answer is great but if you are using QGIS 3 and above you can use the simpler `'Select by Value'` instead of `'Select by Expression'`.

[image: Select by Value 1]

Simply put the value in the field that has the data you are interested in here I am using the `"FID"` field.

[image: eSelect by Value 2]